# Find and replace custom attribute values in AD using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, custom-attributes

So I have an interesting script I am trying to figure out, basically I need to change a custom attribute value to a new one.  The problem is its for both users and computers and not specific to the groups. So for instance the value might be Billing1 for several users in an OU and this need to be Billing2.  So I need to find any instance of the Value of Billing1 and change it to Billing2 not knowing the user or computer object.  I can successfully change one at a time if I know who the user is by using Set-ADUser, Set-ADComputer and even with Set-AdObject but I need to figure out a Find and replace function.

I have searched for this and I have found examples of where I can use CSV for users and computers but again I don't know who has what since the value in the attribute can vary and also changes if a reorg happens.

Answer (score 0):

got the correct script...

Get-ADComputer -Properties enterattributename -Filter {enterattributename -like "value to search" } |Set-ADComputer –replace @{ enterattributename =”value to change”}

this also can be applied to Get-ADUser and Get-ADObject